# Disable 'Download This Video' Real Player Button In Browser

Tags: javascript, flash, flv, realplayer

Is there any way to disable the "Download This Video" button from RealPlayer. It seems that when users have RealPlayer installed on their machines, it automatically adds a "Download This Video" button to any SWF that loads an FLV.

Edit: My intention isn't to prevent someone from downloading the SWF or FLV, I would just like to remove the ugly button that RealPlayer adds on top of my Flash content.

Comment: Should probably add a statement explaining why you want to do this (as you did in your comment for an answer below) since I considered downvoting before reading your explanation, as I'm sure many others will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pointless attempt to control something that can easily be circumvented. This is the same argument as "how can I prevent people from saving the images off my site".

There's always a way.

For example: http://www.downloadhelper.net/

Comment: I don't want to prevent people from downloading the SWF, they can go ahead and download it. My problem is that RealPlayer plasters a big ugly button over my content.

Comment: Ok, then you may be able to put a cleverly-placed DIV over top of the player. Make sure you have "wmode=opaque" on your player parameters.

Answer (score 0):

After you embed the Flash content, remove the following attribute from the embedding tag:

```
type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
```

You will notice that the download button will disappears because it can't tell what exactly the content is. But this is only a hack, not the best practice of getting the task done.

Answer (score 0):

there is an easy way of removing that download video thing from chrome and I found it.  Click on it, then click the wheel to open the settings for Real Player,  then just turn it off.

it took me a while, as no one has ever answered that question before.